# How do I get rid of the "cannot import outside module" error in my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, google-chrome-extension, node-modules

I'm creating a chrome extension for making it easier to type emojis. So when you type :sob: anywhere on your computer, it'll get converted to regardless of website. For this I'm importing a module called emoji-dictionary, and even though I have type:module in my package.json, when I go to the manage extensions page on chrome it says "cannot import outside of module".

Ty for any help :)

I've already tried adding type:module to package.json and even to manifest.json, but its not really working.